# Streamlit error in jupyter notebook background

Tags: background, jupyter, streamlit

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6872/2503841040.py in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().system('nohup streamlit run app.py&')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py in system_piped(self, cmd)
    620             # os.system() or use ip.system=ip.system_raw
    621             # if they really want a background process.
--> 622             raise OSError("Background processes not supported.")
    623 
    624         # we explicitly do NOT return the subprocess status code, because

OSError: Background processes not supported.
```

Comment: nohup is a background process, and it appears that get_ipython is telling you that's not allowed.

Comment: Okay but then what m I supposed to do? m new to this

Comment: Instead of running a terminal from inside of Jupyter Notebook, you can run `streamlit run app.py` in a regular terminal on your computer. You could even use nohup if you desire.